# how to validate a file download using mocha assert in javascipt

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have an async function downloadFile() which accepts given name of a file and saves it in the project directory. It is defined in 'savefile.js'

I am trying to write mocha test for validating if the file is present in directory after download.
but it is failing. file is being downloaded correctly, but assertion is failing. It seems assertion gets executed before file is available. it takes only fraction of second ( unnoticeable) to get file downloaded. I am trying to make use of 'done' here, but something is going wrong.

if I re-execute the test without deleting 'testFile.dat' which was downloaded earlier, test gets passed, it means assertion gets called before file is available and thus fails!

what change I should make to have the assertion executed once file is downloaded?

```
import assert from 'assert';
import {downloadFile} from './src/savefile.js';
import appRoot from 'app-root-path';

const fs = require('fs')

describe("save file", () => {
    it("file should be saved", (done) => { 
        downloadFile('testFile.dat');
        const f = appRoot.resolve('testFile.dat');
        console.log(f);
        assert(fs.existsSync(f));
        done();
    });
});
```

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION] [ERR_ASSERTION]: expected file E:\project\testFile.dat is not found
+ expected - actual

```
  -false
  +true

  at Context.<anonymous> (E:/project/src/savefile.spec.js:14:9)
  at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the done parameter and use an `async` test function, so you can `await` your `downloadFile` result:

```
it("file should be saved", async () => { 
    await downloadFile('testFile.dat'); // <-- await for the download
    const f = appRoot.resolve('testFile.dat');
    console.log(f);
    assert(fs.existsSync(f));
});
```

### Explanation

When you use `done` as a parameter, mocha needs to intercept a `done()` call to flag the test as completed. When you avoid this parameter, mocha will process the function as a promise. See https://mochajs.org/#using-async-await